# Выполнение задач в Docker-контейнере в Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция

Может ли Jenkins работать так же, как [GitLab Runner + Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html):

1. Из образа развернуть контейнер.
2. Внутрь контейнера клонировать репозиторий git, выполнить произвольные команды.
3. Выделить артефакты и сохранить их вне контейнера, свернуть контейнер (завершить его работу).

> **Вопрос**: нужна пошаговая инструкция по настройке Jenkins для выполнения трех вышеуказанных шагов.

Нашел [Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin). Вроде бы он умеет разворачивать Jenkins slave в докере, подключать его к мастеру и утилизировать после использования. Этот вариант мне точно не подходит, потому что нужно тащить в сборочное окружение Java и прочие не нужные там вещи. Базовый образ `jenkins-slave` весит в 100 раз больше `alpine`, это вообще за гранью разумного.

```
docker images                                                                                                              
REPOSITORY              ...     SIZE
alpine                  ...     3.97 MB
evarga/jenkins-slave    ...     368 MB
```

Еще нашел плагин [Docker build step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin). Одна из фич — "create new container from image". Возможно, мне нужно именно это, но я не понимаю, как выполнить пункты 2 и 3.

Comment: Либо тянуть полноценный слейв, либо вручную (exec / баш скрипт в cmd) осуществлять все действия с репозиторием и разбираться с ключами для доступа к репозиторию. Иначе, боюсь, никак.

Comment: Хотя вроде как есть возможность использования SSH-слейвов, на которые дженкинс сам установит агент, но там все равно нужна будет джава + будет тратиться время непосредственно на установку

Comment: @etki т.е. внутрь контейнера записать ключ в `.ssh/`, поставить git, клонировать репозиторий?

Comment: @etki Ок, возможно я поддался XY-проблеме. Есть ли более простые способы выполнять задачи на Jenkins в чистом [«фениксовом»](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PhoenixServer.html) окружении?

Comment: Да, плюс еще всякие мелочи типа борьбы с незаполненным known_hosts. Других способов не знаю, но это не значит, что их нет. Сам в свое время решил, что лучше иметь один гигантский образ со всем, чем можно (rvm, nvm, phpbrew, jabba + непосредственно установленные основные версии самого ПО + всякие phantomjs), чем идти другим путем.

Comment: У Вас уже собраный есть Docker Image, Вы хотите его стартовать, а потом в нем выполнять всевозможные комнды? верно я понимаю суть вопроса?

Comment: @nick_gabpe да, и ко всему этому нужна обертка, чтобы можно было выполнять задачи автоматически на Jenkins'е.

Comment: Дык, pipeline же есть, он Вам не подходит? Несколько месяцев назад писал howto , гляньте мельком оно или нет https://avalon.is74.ru/blog/?p=390

Comment: @nobody сами по себе pipeline'ы задачу не решают, т.к. по умолчанию в дженкинсе сборка все равно в грязном окружении происходит. Но ваша статья вроде бы как раз про то, что мне нужно. Читаю.

Comment: @nobody я пока что довольствуюсь GitLab CI, но есть риск, что придется переходить на Jenkins. Для этого и разведываю.

Comment: @NickVolynkin если вкратце, то в моей статье я создаю с помощью pipeline'а сначала docker-контейнер (в примере maven), затем клонирую туда некий код из git и делаю с ним нечто, что можно описать либо в pipline , либо прямо в том же проекте git (или в другом), либо запустив shell-код. Артефакты все собираются из этого контейнера в jenkins и их можно скачать из вебы. К сожалению подробно я этого не описывал, но это дефолтная фишка. В конце - контейнер удаляется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Jenkins можно выполнить bash/batch команду, для bash это будет примерно так:

```
docker run -it -d my_image  # запускам image в detached моде
docker exec $(docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=my_image) bash -c "cd your_path; your_command" # запускаем Вашу команду в контейнере.

list=$(docker exec  $(docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=my_image)  bash -c 'ls /path/to/artifacts/inside/container') # создаем список артефактов, которые мы будем вытаскивать из контенера
for i in $list; do  docker cp $(docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=my_image):$i ./path/to/outside container ; done # вытаскиваем артефакты согласно списку

for i in $(docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=my_image); do docker rm $(docker stop $i); done # удалям контейнеры, если они работают
```

Comment: Проверить сегодня не успею, но награду вручу — конкурс кончается.

Comment: Спасибо, в итоге я обошелся GitLab CI, но это решение мне все равно скоро пригодится.

Comment: рад, что поможет